# How to limit the search index fields in Magento?

Tags: magento2.2, elasticsearch

We are using elastic search 6.x and facing search index limit exceeded error. As per this doc

> https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360003290654-Exception-on-category-page-with-Elasticsearch-5-0-Limit-of-total-fields-1000-in-index-has-been-exceeded
>   How can we limit the search index fields in Magento? Any body knows where that setting or config resides in Magento

Comment: did you try the solution in the documentation?

Comment: Decrease the number of fields in your search index or increase the limit using the index.mapping.total_fields.limit setting (create a new Elasticsearch template with an increased setting). In this solutions I don't know where to decrease the number of search index in Magento

Comment: "Decrease the number of fields in your search index", How to decease this fields? and where?